# Скачать файл с сервера Flask

Tags: python, flask

Вопрос такой, имеется фреймворк фласк, где я загружаю файл на сервер, обрабатываю его и после сохраняю в отдельную папку.
Прописал ссылку на данный файл, файл на сервере присутствует в нужной папке, но когда я хочу скачать файл, то получаю:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Нужен ли отдельный метод по обработке файлов на сервере и отдаче по запросу клиенту?

В шаблоне стоит ссылка вида:

```
<h1>Результат</h1>
Скачать файл:
a href="/uploads/result/{{the_prediction}}.xlsx">Скачать</a
<br/>
```

Comment: На сервер тоже нужно добавлять обработку и возврат файлов, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2b043f683e4dcb305a7389ccb83da9f6cf4845f9/flask__webservers/upload_and_download_files/main.py#L60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши ссылки должны быть прописаны в `@app.route()`

```
from flask import send_from_directory
from os import path

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download():
    directory = path.join(app.root_path, app.config['FOLDER_WIT_FILE'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=directory, filename=filename)
```

Comment: Печалька, я думал браузер подтягивает с нужной папки :)

Comment: @sanitarn, браузер сделает запрос на сервер, а тот возвращает в ответе

Comment: Еще есть вариант сохранять такие файлы в папку static/, тогда @app.route() будет не нужен